# Must EVERY computer on a Network belong to a Domain?

Tags: windows-10, security, domain

I have a small doctor's office that leverages a domain controller and I want to add a machine that will act as a server for a very specific purpose.

The server will host an application that is NOT used by users, per se, but by two client medical machines that are also on the network. The client machines are eye examination machines that hold patient records that reside ONLY on these machines currently.

The purpose of adding a server is to host an application that will grab data from patients on all eye machines, run some analytics, and then host the record on its local drive.

Questions:

- Does this server HAVE to be connected to the domain?
- What problems might I expect if it were not connected?
- Is there such a thing as a network in which some machines are not joined to the domain?

I am asking because the machine I bought to act as a server has Windows 10 Home, not Pro. The machine is very robust: i7 processor, 12GM RAM and 2TB HD.

If I do need to upgrade to Windows Pro, so I can have active directory, how easy or hard is that?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: The purpose of a domain is to provide consistency and control over computers. A domain allows access control and security and makes allows for secure communication between the members of the domain. You don't HAVE to join a specific computer to a domain.

HOWEVER, at risk of sounding brusque: What you are considering doing is, to put it very nicely, unwise.

Where this is going to bite you in the butt:

- Getting the computers to talk to each other. You're going to have to be much more clever than you sound to get your combination of domain and non-domain, Pro and Home computers to talk to each other.
- Getting the computers to talk to each other SECURELY. Part of what a domain does is provides consistent security requirements and allows for confirmation of the security settings. You might get the computers to talk to each other, but in all likelihood, you'll do so by opening the whole thing up to the wide world. I wonder what the HIPAA people will say about that when all your patient records show up on a torrent server or for sale on the dark web in a week.

What you really need is a basic file server for backups. Heck, it wouldn't hardly cost as much as you probably spent on the "i7 processor, 12GM RAM and 2TB HD" machine to get a basic Synology that can be easily set up as a decent and relatively secure backup solution, even for the domain machines.

Yes, this is a serious issue and I am using serious words because you're talking about EXTREMELY private information that there are VERY SERIOUS laws guarding. Putting in place an incorrect solution WILL cause problems, and not just financial for you or the doctor. The patients whose information has been stolen due to gross mismanagement will have no recourse.

Take your time. Research. Spend the right money in the right way. Do it right. Ask questions here and elsewhere. Let us help.